# Doctrine 2 LEFT JOIN doesn't retrieve all columns

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've got a strange problem with Doctrine Query, with Symfony 2.3

(by advance, sorry for the english/french terms in my queries .. :s )

When, in my controller, I launch a findAll() query on one of my Repositories, the following query is generated:

```
SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.date AS date2, t0.projet_id AS projet_id3, t0.societe_id AS societe_id4, t0.user_id AS user_id5 FROM Estimate t0
```

Thus, I get all my columns including the ones involving relationships.
But I need to add leftJoin on my query. I created a custom query:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('e')
    ->addSelect('e')
    ->leftJoin('e.works', 'w')
    ->addSelect('w')
    ->leftJoin('w.tache', 't')
    ->addSelect('t')
    ->leftJoin('t.groupetache', 'g')
    ->addSelect('g')
    ;
```

and now, I got all the joined column, but for my main table "Estimate", the query only returns id and date (the following query is generated:)

```
SELECT e0_.id AS id0, e0_.date AS date1, w1_.id AS id4, w1_.description AS description5, w1_.prix_ha AS prix_ha6, w1_.prix_vente AS prix_vente7, t2_.id AS id8, t2_.nom AS nom9, t2_.prix_achat AS prix_achat10, g3_.id AS id11, g3_.nom AS nom12 FROM Estimate e0_ LEFT JOIN Work w1_ ON e0_.id = w1_.estimate_id LEFT JOIN Tache t2_ ON w1_.tache_id = t2_.id LEFT JOIN GroupeTaches g3_ ON t2_.groupetache_id = g3_.id
```

Am I missing a point ?

There's a way to get all my main table fields, + joined fields right ?

My "manual" query on Sequel Pro returns what I want, I tried to change my query with a DQL one, like this :

```
$query = $this->getEntitymanager()
    ->createQuery('
        SELECT e0_.id AS id0, e0_.date AS date1, e0_.id AS id2, e0_.date AS date3,
        e0_.projet_id AS projet_id3, e0_.societe_id AS societe_id4, e0_.user_id AS user_id5,
        w1_.id AS id4, w1_.description AS description5, w1_.prix_ha AS prix_ha6, w1_.prix_vente AS prix_vente7,
        t2_.id AS id8, t2_.nom AS nom9, t2_.prix_achat AS prix_achat10, g3_.id AS id11, g3_.nom AS nom12
        FROM EcomCrmBundle:Estimate e0_
        LEFT JOIN EcomCrmBundle:Work w1_ WITH e0_.id = w1_.estimate_id
        LEFT JOIN EcomCrmBundle:Tache t2_ WITH w1_.tache_id = t2_.id
        LEFT JOIN EcomCrmBundle:GroupeTaches g3_ WITH t2_.groupetache_id = g3_.id');
```

but I've got an error, saying Estimate doesn't have a projet_id field :(

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Could we see our entity ?

Comment: I guess you could try clearing the cache and such.  Is there any chance you have two copies of the database around?  Using multiple entity managers?  Two copies of EcomCrmBundle:Estimate?  Doing both queries in the same controller action one right after the other?  Very strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just guessing but what method do you use to retrieve your results ? getArrayResult() ?
Try with getResult(). It should select every row in "Estimate".